# How do find transmission delay of a network?

Tags: networking, delay, formula, transmission

In my book it says that transmission delay=(length of the packet)/(transmission speed).  However in all of the study problems they do not follow this logic.  For example, they ask for the transmission delay of a 1,000 byte packet over a 1Mbps connection.  I get 1 microsecond, but somehow they get 8.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a byte is not a bit.

Comment: I feel so dumb.  For some reason I was under the impression that Mbps stood for Megabytes per second and not Megabits per second.  Makes perfect sense now.  Of course they failed to mention that in the book.